# PHP function and assignment: confusion between echo and return

Tags: php, function, return-value

For example:

```
function countdown() 
{
  echo "4, 3, 2, 1, ";
  return "blastoff!";
}

$return_value = countdown();
echo $return_value;
```

When the `countdown()` function is invoked it will print `4, 3, 2, 1`

Also `echo $return_value;` will give `blastoff!`

But how?

I mean if `$return_value = countdown();` So, `$return_value` should give value of `countdown()` that is `4, 3, 2, 1`

Please help me to resolve this confusion!!

Answer (score 1):

So echo is just printing to the screen.  That will happen where ever you call echo.  Your return is returning the string "Blastoff!" So when you call your function countdown() it will display 4, 3, 2, 1, on the screen and then return the string "Blastoff!" which you then are assigning that value "Blastoff!" to the variable named $return_value and then you echo that variable which has a value of "Blastoff!".  Hope that helps make a little more sense of what is happening.

Answer (score 0):

The only value returned by `countdown()` is **'blastoff!'**, that's why this string is the **only assigned** to `$return_value`.

`echo '4, 3, 2, 1, ';` is just something the function `countdown()`  must do *before finally returning* **'blastoff!'**.

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

It's because `echo` is a function that simply outputs whatever it's followed by (`4, 3, 2, 1,`) in this case. The string '4, 3, 2, 1, ' doesn't ever get stored or passed anywhere (i.e. it's not returned by the function).

If you wanted to return the full string you have to explicitly tell the function to do so:

```php
function countdown() 
{
  $countdown = "4, 3, 2, 1, ";
  return $countdown."blastoff!";
}

$return_value = countdown();
echo $return_value;

// Output: 4, 3, 2, 1, blastoff!
```

Alternatively, if you just wanted to return "4, 3, 2, 1, ":

```php
function countdown() 
{
  $countdown = "4, 3, 2, 1, ";
  return $countdown;
}

$return_value = countdown();
echo $return_value;

// Output: 4, 3, 2, 1,
```